# How to determine state in a column based on two other Boolean columns for a timeseries Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

Given the first dataframe is there a way with pandas[.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift), [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas-dataframe-diff), [.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace), or [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to accomplish column D of the second dataframe or if not, how might it be done?

It is useful to know that iterating from the top down, rows in column D stay True once a row in column B is True and only as long as no True is encountered in column C. Essentially this is determining state based on B and C.

```
                     A      B      C
2019-05-04 00:15:00  1   True  False
2019-05-04 00:30:00  2  False  False
2019-05-04 00:45:00  2  False  False
2019-05-04 01:00:00  3  False  True
2019-05-04 01:15:00  1  False  False
2019-05-04 01:30:00  2  False  False
2019-05-04 01:45:00  2  True   False
2019-05-04 02:00:00  3  False  False
2019-05-04 02:15:00  1  False  False
2019-05-04 02:30:00  2  False  True
2019-05-04 02:45:00  2  False  False
2019-05-04 03:00:00  3  False  False

                     A      B      C      D
2019-05-04 00:15:00  1   True  False  True
2019-05-04 00:30:00  2  False  False  True
2019-05-04 00:45:00  2  False  False  True
2019-05-04 01:00:00  3  False  True   False
2019-05-04 01:15:00  1  False  False  False
2019-05-04 01:30:00  2  False  False  False
2019-05-04 01:45:00  2  True   False  True
2019-05-04 02:00:00  3  False  False  True
2019-05-04 02:15:00  1  False  False  True
2019-05-04 02:30:00  2  False  True   False
2019-05-04 02:45:00  2  False  False  False
2019-05-04 03:00:00  3  False  False  False
```

**Functionalized Solutions**

@jezrael (import numpy as np required)

```
def determine_state(df,x,y,z):
  """Given a dataframe where columns x and y are Booleans
  displaying the entering and exit of a Boolean state, create 
  a third column that displays the state."""

  # use numpy.select with forward filling missing values 
  df[z] = np.select([df[x], df[y]], [True, False], None)

  # replace first Nones by False if exist
  df[z] = df[z].ffill().fillna(False)

  return df
```

@run-out

```
def determine_state(df,x,y,z):
  """Given a dataframe where columns x and y are Booleans
  displaying the entering and exit of a Boolean state, create 
  a third column that displays the state."""

  # set column z to False
  df[z] = False

  # filter column x for True and set z to True
  df.loc[df[x], z] = True

  # filter column y for True and set z to False
  df.loc[df[y], z] = False

  # forward fill on z
  df[z] = df[z].ffill(axis=0)

  return df
```

Comment: I don't get the logic behind D. A bit more explanation might help

Comment: @zero Row-wise top-down, when True is encountered in B, D becomes True and stays True. When True is encountered in C, D becomes False and stays False.

Comment: Maybe this might be accomplished referencing previous rows in an apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with forward filling missing values and last replace first `None`s by `False` if exist:

```
import numpy as np

df['D'] = np.select([df['B'], df['C']], [True, False], None)
df['D'] = df['D'].ffill().fillna(False)
print (df)
                     A      B      C      D
2019-05-04 00:15:00  1   True  False   True
2019-05-04 00:30:00  2  False  False   True
2019-05-04 00:45:00  2  False  False   True
2019-05-04 01:00:00  3  False   True  False
2019-05-04 01:15:00  1  False  False  False
2019-05-04 01:30:00  2  False  False  False
2019-05-04 01:45:00  2   True  False   True
2019-05-04 02:00:00  3  False  False   True
2019-05-04 02:15:00  1  False  False   True
2019-05-04 02:30:00  2  False   True  False
2019-05-04 02:45:00  2  False  False  False
2019-05-04 02:00:00  3  False  False  False
```

Comment: I assume this also requires importing numpy as np, which is a formality because pandas is already using it behind the scene. It could also be referenced with pd.np.select...

Comment: @Liquidgenius - Yes, this is 2 possible solutions - I like more first.

Answer (score 1):

First filter column 'B' for True and set 'D' to True

```
df.loc[df['B'], 'D'] = True
```

Then do the same for 'C' but set to False

```
df.loc[df['C'], 'D'] = False
```

Forward fill on 'D'

```
df['D'] = df['D'].ffill(axis=0)
```

And fillna for any at the beginning of the column.

```
df['D'].fillna(False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This provides a correct answer. I did not technically provide the best example. Based on this answer, how would you backfill the NaN in column D if True did not occur until the second row of column B?

Comment: I guess logically, any NaNs would automatically be False.

Comment: Yeah you would just have NaNs there, so you would be set.

Comment: @jezrael is the preferred solution.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and working response. I up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
df['D'] = np.nan
df.loc[ df['B'] == True , 'D'] = True
df.loc[ df['C'] == True , 'D'] = False
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```